# objects framed in a rectangle

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, shapes

In this image you can see a blue selection on which I have put my pointer. My question is - how do you achieve that there is a rectangle which frames objects to be only visible inside of the rectangle although the objects are actually bigger than the rectangle and spreading outside of it? And also - how do I make it the opposite, how do I get to see the objects that are outside of the rectangle, meaning the selection that I have selected?

Thanks already!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The method of doing this is called the CLIPPING MASK. A clipping mask is an object whose shape masks other artwork so that only areas that lie within the shape are visible

The following guidelines apply to creating clipping masks:

1. The objects that you mask are moved into the clipping mask’s group in the Layers panel if they don’t already reside there.
2. Only vector objects can be clipping masks; however, any artwork can be masked.
3. If you use a layer or group to create a clipping mask, the first object in the layer or group masks everything that is a subset of the layer or group.
4. Regardless of its previous attributes, a clipping mask changes to an object with no fill or stroke.

And the answer of your second question is:

You can simply double click on your selection, it will take you the the isolation mode where you can preview and edit your selected object.